# How to disable hardware acceleration in the X-window server file in ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: 16.04

Software enviroment:Ubuntu 16.04(kernel:4.9.38 with xenomai 3.0.5)
Description:when I run latency test_suite,there are high latencies showing up in Ternminal;almost other possible reason that cause this badness;so I wanna disable hardware acceleration for X-window,but what should I do next?